# Parsing .rst files within a Github repo

Tags: python, parsing, restructuredtext

I'm trying to parse .rst documents that are being used to publish API docs. I'm pulling the .rst documents from a Github repo. But, I don't know what to do from there. I've been encountering some issues. I think that if I'm able to parse them locally, I can figure out how to do it by using the Github API, so here's what I have so far.

1. I cloned the Github repo locally.
2. I wrote some code to parse 1 of the .rst documents
   2a. I'm encountering errors within this step

```
import docutils
from docutils import nodes
from docutils.parsers.rst import Parser

with open("data/repos/public_api_client/sdk_docs/autodoc/api_reference.rst") as f:
    rst_content = f.read()

def rst_to_plain_text(node):
    if isinstance(node, nodes.Text):
        return node.astext()
    elif isinstance(node, nodes.paragraph):
        return ' '.join(rst_to_plain_text(child) for child in node.children)

# Parse the RST content
parser = Parser()
parsed_document = docutils.utils.new_document('rst_content') # include settings?
parser.parse(rst_content, parsed_document)

# Convert parsed RST content to plain text
plain_text = rst_to_plain_text(parsed_document)


print(plain_text)
```

Here is the error I'm encountering:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/workspace/rfp-monster/data_scripts/testing.py", line 114, in <module>
    parser.parse(rst_content, parsed_document)
  File "/Users/workspace/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/docutils/parsers/rst/__init__.py", line 184, in parse
    self.statemachine.run(inputlines, document, inliner=self.inliner)
  File "/Users/workspace/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/docutils/parsers/rst/states.py", line 157, in run
    inliner.init_customizations(document.settings)
  File "/Users/john.eastman/workspace/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/docutils/parsers/rst/states.py", line 607, in init_customizations
    if settings.pep_references:
AttributeError: 'Values' object has no attribute 'pep_references'
```

If someone can help me figure this out, I'll post the code to do this with the Github Python API!
Also, here is a snippet of the .rst file-->

```
API Reference
#############

.. _api_object_api:

API Object
==========

.. autoclass:: mime.models.api_object.APIObject
   :members:

.. _advanced_options_api:

Advanced Options
================

.. autoclass:: mime.helpers.AdvancedOptions
   :members:

.. _anomaly_assessment_api:
```

Comment: A guess: api_reference.rst contains markup that requires Sphinx in order to be properly processed (just Docutils is not enough).

Comment: Sphinx adds many features on top of the basic ones provided by Docutils. The `autoclass` directive is one such feature.

Comment: Thank you, @mzjn, I will look for a Sphinx tutorial.